# Devise restrict sign up to Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I am working on a Rails App that uses Devise as the authentication module, however I want to customize it so that CanCan will only permit Administrators to create a new user.  I am having a hard time understanding how to customize the controller for Devise so that this can be done.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Basically you would need to restrict controller actions to your admin role. I would recomend looking into CanCan for this, you can restrict the actions on models using a simple definition file. Here is the project page with a nice readme and wiki: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a "User" controller that will manage users and then simply set permissions for it. So in your new User controller you can have something like:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
  end

  def new
  end

  def show
  end

  def create
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created User." 
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    params[:user].delete(:password) if params[:user][:password].blank?
    params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation) if params[:user][:password].blank? and params[:user][:password_confirmation].blank?
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated User."
      redirect_to user_index_path
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    if @user.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully deleted User."
      redirect_to user_index_path
    end
  end

end
```

Assuming you have administrators set to:

```
can :manage, :all
```

You should be good to go.

In your routes file you'll need to set up your routes:

```
resources :user, :controller => "user"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This will break devise miserably, and will not solve the problem. To make this work: add a prefix to devise (devise_for :users, :path_prefix => ‘d’) and make sure you add your resource AFTER devise_for. Don't to remove :registerable from Users. Also, this controller is not adding the authorization filter required by devise. Try that: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-CanCan-+-Devise,-The-easy-way.  (wrote myself)

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to customize anything :D

- Remove :registerable from your Devise model.
- Create your Users CRUD* (just scaffold users)
- Use CanCan for user permission on your Users
  Controller.

*Check Devise's wiki on how to create a Users CRUD, there is a routing trick you need to do